# Adding php code within a template file

Tags: php, templates

I have the following code that is within a file called footer.php

```
<section class="landing-form">
 <form action="%TEMPLATE_DIRECORY_URI%/multipurpose-sliders-templates/slider11/landing-page-form.php" method="post">
<h2>%FORM_TITLE%</h2>
<p class="dsc">Enter your details below and we'll call you.</p>
```

I would like to include some PHP within the file, but when I add some it doesn't render. I'm not familiar with the %variable%. Is there any way to add PHP code to this type of file?

Comment: that's probably some templating engine BUILT on top of php, but the posted code is NOT php by and of itself.

Comment: if you use include("footer.php") or includeonce/require/requireonce PHP should be preprocessed...

Comment: What is the templating system your using?  Generally, the point of templates is not to have server side code in them.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a mark up from ASP, not PHP.  In order to do this in PHP do the following:

Create a new file to hold your variable.  Name it var.php.  In there:

```
<?php $formTitle = 'Whatever you want' ?>
```

In the HTML of your PHP page,

```
<? include 'var.php'; ?>
```

And in your HTML

```
<h2><? echo $formTitle ?></h2>
```

I must reiterate that this must be done in a PHP page on a server that is running PHP.  This will not work with straight HTML.  This will not work on a server that is not executing PHP.

But there you have a simple example how this is supposed to work.

Comment: also php has a <?= $formTitle ?> tag form. It's the same as <? echo $formTitle; ?>

Comment: I know this is true, and it's supposed to work.  But for some reason, I always find echo to be more reliable.